# How to display specific page and item using carousel plugin

Tags: jquery, select, backbone.js, haml, carousel

Hi I am using carousel plugin to implement a horizontal scrolling for my topics view

[image]

And what happens on the page is this:

1) User can scroll to a few page to the right to search for topics

2) User clicks on topic he/she likes

3) The whole page re-renders i.e. the topics section and the section below will all re-render

4) The topic section will be reset and the first page of the topic scrolling will be displayed again

How can I keep track of which item in the carousel list was being selected so that I can display it when the page is re-rendered? Also, how do I shift the scrolling to the correct page to display the selected topic?

Snippet of my current implementation is as follows:

```
//Appending topics in carousel plugin (question page view)
addAllTopics: ->
  @options.topics.each(@addOneTopic)
  Onethingaday.Public.checkActive(Backbone.history.fragment)

  @$('li.all_topics').show()

  $('#my-carousel').carousel({
    itemsPerPage: 4,
    itemsPerTransition: 4,
    speed: 500,
    noOfRows: 1,
    nextPrevLinks: true,
    pagination: true,
    easing: 'swing'
  })

addOneTopic: (topic) ->
  if topic.get('question_count') > 0
    $(@el).find('ul.topics').append @topic_template(topic.toJSON())

//individual @topic_template - on click on topic, the route of '/topics/topic_slug' will be triggered which rerenders the whole questions page
%li
  %a{href: "/topics/<%= topic.slug %>", :'data-active' => "/topics/<%= topic.slug %>", slug: "<%= topic.slug %>", text: "<%= topic.text %>" } #<%= topic.slug %>
```